# fetch IP address through gwmi classes apart from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class

Tags: powershell

I want to retrieve IP address through powershell using GWMI but not using Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration classs. Please help.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell? If you are on a recent version, what's wrong with Get-NetIPAddress?

Comment: have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: well i am on DC and running script to fetch IP,DNS and MAC from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration but data is not coming back to me.

Comment: servers for which i am running scripts are 2003,2008,2012

Comment: How you are fetching. Edit and Post the code

Comment: i am using gwmi class for fetching data from remote computers but newtwork adapter is not working

Comment: could you post the code. How you are using the wmi to fetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple approaches . It depends on your PS version and requirement:

**Dot Net method**:

```
[net.dns]::GetHostAddresses("") | Select -ExpandProperty IPAddressToString
```

Native PS command using **test-connection** (equivalent to ping):

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName ::1 -Count 1 |Select-Object -Property IPv*Address
```

**From Registry key:**

```
Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\system\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces| foreach{get-itemProperty $_.PSPath -N *IPAdd* -EA 0}|select *IP*
```

**Using Ipconfig:**

```
(ipconfig)-like'*IPv4*'|foreach{($_-split': ')[-1]}
```

If you are in PS Version 3 or above and Windows 8 / Server 2012 or above then directly you can use:

`(Get-NetIPAddress).IPAddress` or `(Get-NetIPConfiguration).IPv4Address`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why downvoted on this answer?  at least show the reason. the guy is looking for ipaddress fetching other that Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration  and wmi class